# Are SATA power switches safe?

Tags: sata

Those 4-port power switches that connect or disconnect power to SATA drives seem to only switch the 5 volt line on or off and the 12 volt line is left on regardless. Is this safe to do? Is the drive motor still running from the 12 volts when it is supposedly in the off position?